# Show that $(\mu + \nu)^-(A) \le \mu^-(A) + \nu^-(A)$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

> **Question:** Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two signed measures on a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$, with $\mu$ is finite. Show that $(\mu + \nu)^-(A) \le \mu^-(A) + \nu^-(A)$

I see it was like the triangle inequality but I don't know how to prove this.

I have tried to solve this problem and this is my result.

**My attempt:** Let $\{X^+, X^-\}$ be a Hahn partition of $\mu + \nu$.

We have $\forall A \in \mathcal{A}$
$$-(\mu + \nu)(A) = (\mu^- + \nu^-)(A) - (\mu^+ + \nu^+)(A) \le (\mu^- + \nu^-)(A)$$ (since $\mu^+$ and $ \nu^+$ are positive measures)

So $(\mu + \nu)^-(A) = -(\mu + \nu)(A \cap X^-) \le (\mu^- + \nu^-)(A \cap X^-) \le (\mu^- + \nu^-)(A)$.

Comment: How do you define $\mu^-$ etc.?